# Replace the J/N with explanation from a single cell in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, replace

In each row of the column of een dataframe I have the following =  (J,N,N,J,N).

So it looks like the following:

| Name | Choices |
| --- | --- |
| Henk | J,N,N,J |
| Tom | N,J,N,N |
| Tim | J,N,J,J |

I would like for the first letter of the choice a value geven. So the first letter of Henk of the choice of Henk is 'J' and of Tom is 'N'. For 'J' I wand to say if 'J' than 'New address' if 'N' then 'Old address'. For the second letter, for Henk is 'N' than i want to give other value for example for 'J' then 'New car' and if 'N' then 'Old car'. So for Henk will be 'Old car'. And so on..

How can i do this with python?

Output

| Name | Choices | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Henk | J,N,N,J | New address, Old car, Old city, New area |
| Tom | N,J,N,N | Old address, New car, Old city, Old area |
| Tim | J,N,J,J | New address, Old car, New city, New area |

Comment: The explanation need clarification and you should provide the **full exact output**, maybe with one more row

Comment: start with defining a comprehensible mapping between those letter `J etc.` and `New/Old address etc.`, also how do choices and cells relate?

Comment: I have updated the output example.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [['Hank', 'J,N,N,J'], ['Tom', 'N,J,J,N'], ['Tim', 'J,N,J,J']]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Choices'])


df['address'] = df['Choices'].astype(str).str[0]
df['car'] = df['Choices'].astype(str).str[2]
df['city'] = df['Choices'].astype(str).str[4]
df['area'] = df['Choices'].astype(str).str[6]

df1 = df.iloc[:,2:6]

for i in df1:
  df[i] = df[i].str.replace("N" , "Old "+str(i))
  df[i] = df[i].str.replace("J" , "New "+str(i))

df["Explanation"] = df[['address', 'city', 'area', 'car']].agg(','.join, axis=1)

df = df.drop('address', axis=1)
df = df.drop('car', axis=1)
df = df.drop('city', axis=1)
df = df.drop('area', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
mappings = [
    {"J": "New address", "N": "Old address"},
    {"J": "New car", "N": "Old car"},
    {"J": "New city", "N": "Old city"},
    {"J": "New area", "N": "Old area"},
]

df["Explanation"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: ",".join(
        mappings[i][ch] for i, ch in enumerate(map(str.strip, x["Choices"].split(",")))
    ),
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Name  Choices                            Explanation
0  Henk  J,N,N,J  New address,Old car,Old city,New area
1   Tom  N,J,N,N  Old address,New car,Old city,Old area
2   Tim  J,N,J,J  New address,Old car,New city,New area
```